# Fade out is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

My purpose: I am trying to create a fadeout event using Javascript.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

function changeOpacity(){

 var finalOpacity = 0 ;
 var currentOpacity = document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity ;
 if(currentOpacity > finalOpacity){
  currentOpacity = currentOpacity - 0.01;
  document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity = currentOpacity ;
  setTimeout(function(){changeOpacity();},10);   
 }
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">

#slide{
 opacity:1;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 background:green;
}

</style>

</head>


<body>

 <div id="slide" ></div>
 <button  onclick="changeOpacity();">Slide</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am learning Javascript. It will be helpful if you help me to correct the code with a little explanation

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does anything happen? Nothing? Errors in the browser console?

Comment: It is working if I put: 
 <div id="slide"  style=" opacity:1;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 background:green;"></div>
 <button  onclick="changeOpacity();">Slide</button>

Comment: external css is not working.

Comment: Yes, because the `style.opacity` property returns the value of the inline style. It doesn't return the opacity set via the stylesheet. Try using `window.getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work with external css like code that I have posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that you cannot access styles set by `CSS` via `element.style`. You need to use `getComputedStyle(element)` instead.

So, in your example, just change

```
var currentOpacity = document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity;
```

to

```
var currentOpacity = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("slide")).opacity;
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvtp3ts4/)

Please be aware, that an element with `opacity: 0` will still take up it's designated space. `opacity: 0` doesn't have the same effect as `display: none`

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to initialise your start opacity value:

```
 var currentOpacity = document.getElementById("slide").style.opacity || 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also decide to add the proper opacity inside the DOM with :

```
<div id="slide" style="opacity:1;"></div>
```

Because the element.style.opacity js property only fetch css properties inside the DOM.